# Determine if any entities exist in CoreData

Tags: core-data, nsfetchrequest

Basically I have set up some up an entity to store some data. However, there will be no entities in CoreData until the user starts to perform some actions. I'm trying to perform some sort of code that just checks to see if any entities exist for a given entity parameter. So if my entity has parameters of name: String and number: Int. I want to know if any entities exist for name: "Example".

I have tried a bunch of different solutions but my apps keeps crashing saying that fetch requests cannot be performed when there are no entities. This is my current code I was trying to use to see if there was anything there.

```
    func isThereFlashCardAccData(cardName: String) -> Bool {
    
    let fR = NSFetchRequest<FlashCardAccuracy>()
    fR.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "cardName == %@", cardName)
    
    do {
        let count = try viewContext.count(for: fR)
        if count == 0 {
            return false
        }else {
            return true
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return false
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Could you include the actual error message, sounds like you have some issue with loading your persistence store. The code you have included looks fine to me.

Comment: "_countWithNoChangesForRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity."

Comment: It wasn't working for me until I force cleaned and changed the Entity name. Try that maybe?

Comment: `let fR = NSFetchRequest<FlashCardAccuracy>()` -> `let fR = NSFetchRequest<FlashCardAccuracy>(entityName: "FlashCardAccuracy")`?

Comment: Given similar questions you could have an issue with viewContext, how is that property initialized ?

Comment: you were correct Joakim, I'm new to this so I was trying to make like a data manager class for a specific entity. Inside that class I created a new @Environment view context variable which was outside of the main view so it was returning null. After I initialed the view context directly form the persistence store it fixed my issue and my initial code worked fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using the fetchRequest() helper function on the entity. Double check your entity name and make sure it matches.

```
func isThereFlashCardAccData(cardName: String) -> Bool {

    let fR = FlashcardEntity.fetchRequest()
    fR.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "cardName == %@", cardName)
    
    do {
        let count = try viewContext.count(for: fR)
        if count == 0 {
            return false
        }else {
            return true
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return false
    }
}
```